# Redirecting when an argument Exception occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

In my action method i have used try - catch block. The method expects an integer parameter and when a null value is passed Server error page is displayed. But i want it to be redirected to a Custom Error page.

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(ArgumentException), View = "~/Views/SetValues/Error")]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
        //if(id==null)
        //{
        //    ViewBag.Error = "A null parameters passed to the function";
        //    return View("Error");
        //}
        try
        {
             .........
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = e.Message;
            return View("Error");
        }
}
```

The try catch block isnt being executed because a null parameter is passed. The if statement  also doesnt work beccause the checking always fail.

**Is there a work around by not setting the parameter nullable?**

Instead of my function redirecting to the server error page i want it to redirect to my custom error page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but try filter attribute:

```
public class IdRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        object parameter = null;
        filterContext.ActionParameters.TryGetValue("id", out parameter);
        var id = parameter as int?;

        if (id == null)
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RequestContext);

            var url = urlHelper.Action("ErrorAction", "ControllerName");

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
        }
    }
}

...

[IdRequiredAttribute]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: i deleted my comment coz it isnt valid anymore. So is it necessary that I write it in all the fucntions where i need this check to performed?

Comment: The redirect works.. But it doesnt return my View. But I should be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The right fix is to make the parameter as nullable and check

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(ArgumentException), View = "~/Views/SetValues/Error")]
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
        if(id==null)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "A null parameters passed to the function";
            return View("Error");
        }
        try
        {
             .........
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = e.Message;
            return View("Error");
        }
}
```

Another point if you don't make it nullable then MVC framework will not reach to your Index action as it will unable to resolve the route. A workaround can be to make the parameter as string and check if you can parse an integer value from it to proceed further.

Comment: But i have already mentioned in the question about a work around without making the parameter nullable. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display custom error page do the following
-->In the Web.config file add this under

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Controller/Action" />
```

and then use this controller and view to display your Error page.

Note:- this can be used for uncaught exception and to avoid yellow pages(error page). However you should use Error logging too for details description.  [Check this link for error logging](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/error-handling-elmah-in-aspnet-mvc.html)

Using this you can also handle 404 and other exception too.